# Асинхронное свойство

Tags: c#, wpf

В программе есть постраничный вывод данных из БД в `DataGrid`.

Данные подгружаются асинхронно порциями при смене номера текущей страницы.

Сейчас сделано так, что в сеттере `CurrentPage` вызывается `LoadProducts`, но т.к. нельзя написать `await`, то метод выполняется синхронно.

Какой такое должно реализовываться?

```
public int CurrentPage
{
    get { return _currentPage; }
    set
    {
        _currentPage = value;
        LoadProducts();
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}

async void LoadProducts()
{
  // Получение данных из БД
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Никак.

Свойство является по существу полем с небольшой довеской. При использовании поля никто не предполагает, что оно будет медленным, асинхронным, или хуже того сможет зависнуть или бросить исключение (если только не присваивать неправильное значение).

Используйте обыкновенную `async`-функцию:

```
public int CurrentPage
{
    get { return _currentPage; }
}

public async Task SwitchToPage(int value)
{
    // Получение данных из БД
    _currentPage = value;
    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(CurrentPage));
}
```

---

Если речь идёт об интерфейсе, тогда, возможно, имеет смысл такое изменение:

```
public int CurrentPage
{
    get { return _currentPage; }
    set
    {
        if (_currentPage == value) return;
        _currentPage = value;
        SwitchToPage(value); // игнорируем возвращаемое значение
        OnPropertyChanged(); // загрузка произойдёт в фоне
    }
}

async Task SwitchToPage(int value)
{
    try
    {
        IsCurrentPageEditable = false;
        // Получение данных из БД
    }
    catch (тут исключения)
    {
        // тут обработка
    }
    finally
    {
        IsCurrentPageEditable = true;
    }
}

bool _isCurrentPageEditable = true;
public bool IsCurrentPageEditable
{
    get { return _isCurrentPageEditable; }
    private set { _isCurrentPageEditable = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
}
```

и в UI

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding CurrentPage}" IsEnabled="{Binding IsCurrentPageEditable}"/>
<TextBlock Text="загрузка..." Visibility="{Binding IsCurrentPageEditable,
        Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
```

Comment: Сейчас у меня `CurrentPage` биндится к `TextBox` и пользователь может менять номер страницы вручную. Получается, что нужно сделать обработку ввода и там вызывать асинхронный метод?

Comment: @maxwell: Ну, можно по-всякому. Вопрос в том, в какой момент вы хотите, чтобы значение `CurrentPage` реально поменялось: до или после обращения к базе?

Comment: Пока сам не знаю, но интуиция подсказывает, что нужно менять после того, как данные получатся из БД. Ведь если изменять до, то может получиться так, что в интерфейсе будут отображаться еще старые данные, а номер страницы уже будет другой.

Comment: @maxwell: Добавил ещё вариант, смотрите.

Comment: А почему загрузка идет в фоне, ведь фактически мы вызываем метод в UI потоке?

Comment: @maxwell: Ну, это зависит от того, как организовано `Получение данных из БД`. Как на мой вкус, там должна вызываться через `await` загрузка в потоке, который работает с базой (я бы назначил для этого отдельный поток).

Comment: Понял, спасибо!